# Flutter getX RangeError Invalid value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

so i'm new to getX package i'm trying to convert my actual app into getX.

I'm having an error that's causing my api response to say this in the console :

```
I/flutter ( 4915): Error 401 
I/flutter ( 4915): Response Body getAllUserBikes 
I/flutter ( 4915): {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token."}
```

**My home_page_controller.dart**

```
 class HomePageController extends GetxController{
      UserController userController = Get.put(UserController());
      StorageController storageController = Get.put(StorageController());
    
      List<Bike> bikeList = [];
      String query = '';
      Rx<UserModel> user = UserModel().obs;
        Color black = Colors.black;
      Color vert = Color.fromARGB(255, 118, 157, 103);
      Color petrole = Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 56, 100);
      Color nocolor = Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 155, 155);
      Color beige = Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 239, 206);
      //Functions
      Color textColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        if (backgroundColor == petrole || backgroundColor == black) {
          return Colors.white;
        } else if (backgroundColor == beige) {
          return black;
        } else {
          return Colors.black;
        }
      }
    
      Color getColorFromString(String stringColor) {
        if (stringColor == "pétrole" || stringColor == "petrole") {
          return petrole;
        } else if (stringColor == "noir") {
          return black;
        } else if (stringColor == "vert eau") {
          return vert;
        } else if (stringColor == "beige") {
          return beige;
        } else {
          return nocolor;
        }
      }
      final bicycodeDefault = [0x14, 0x22, 0x01, 0x00];
      final bicycode = hex.decode(14.toString());
    
     Future<void> initBikeList() async {
      
          List<Bike> list = await APIBike().getAllNotFinishedBikes(jwt: user.value.jwt);
          developer.log('Ma liste = ${list.toString()}');
    
          List<Bike> maList = list;
          for (int i = 0; i == list.length; i++) {
 //RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)
           if (list[i].status == "assembling") {
              maList.first = list[i];
            }
    
            bikeList = maList;
            update();
            
        }
      }
     init() async {
        await initBikeList();
      }
      void onInit() {
        super.onInit();
        init();
        //APIBle().generateBicycode();
      }
      void getStorage() {
        user.value = UserModel.storageFromJson(storageController.getData(key: "user"));
        // print(storageController.getData(key: "user"));
      }
      Future initStorage() async {
        getStorage();
      }
    
    }
```

**my API (only the part where it fetch all the data into a list)**

```
 Future<List<Bike>> getAllNotFinishedBikes({
    required String jwt,
  }) async {
    var client = new http.Client();

    var response = await client
        .get(Uri.parse("$serverAddress/bikes?status=ne_finish"), headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $jwt'
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("SUCCESS getAllNotFinishedBikes");
      print(response);
      developer.log(response.body);
      print("LENGHT");
      developer.log(response.body.length.toString());
      var body = response.body.toString();
      final List<dynamic> parsed = jsonDecode(body) as List<dynamic>;

      /*print("RAW BODY");*/
      print("PARSED");
      print(parsed);
      try {
        List<Bike> listOfBikes = createBikesList(parsed);
        print(parsed.length.toString() + " bike(s) scanned successfully");
        return listOfBikes;
      } catch (e) {
        print(
            "Error while trying to parse parsed json in getAllNotFinishedBikes");
        print(e);
        return [];
      }
    } else {
      print("Error " + response.statusCode.toString());
      print("Response Body getAllUserBikes");
      print(response.body);
      return []; //we return an empty list
    }
  }
```

I feel like the problem is from how i did my controller, maybe a way to make my list observable with getX ?
I can provide more codes if needed.

Thanks u all, help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
for (int i = 0; i == list.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me but it only made my app run but i still has 0 value(in my list.view) and still has 
`/flutter ( 8692): Error 401
I/flutter ( 8692): Response Body getAllUserBikes
I/flutter ( 8692): {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token."}`

I have updated my question with the part of my API request